# Angular Router Guard Error Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, router, guard

Hello I'm trying to create a Router Guard:

My `auth.guard.ts` file:

```
import { CanActivate,
         Router,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    return true; // just for tests gonna change that later
  }
}
```

I import it in `app.module.ts` into providers.

The problem is that I now get this Error:

```
 Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard: (?).
```

What is wrong? How can I fix that? I mean im not even using the Guard in my `APP_ROUTES` yet.

Comment: you forgot `@Injectable()` before the class declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate { ...
```